# Run UI test and skip pop-up

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, google-chrome, authentication

I run the following test which works using [playwright](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright), however **sometimes** I got a certificate popup like below, if I click on cancel button the test proceed and **pass**,
How can I avoid this pop-up, I click on `inspect` button for the cancel button but noting happen.
Any idea how to avoid it? as this is **my** certificate... and it shouldn't  be used on the tests.
How can I overcome this?

[image]

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://app.com');
  await page.fill('input[type="text"]', 'user@test.com');
  await page.fill('input[type="password"]', 'Abcd1234!');
  page.click('button[id="logOnFormSubmit"]');
}
)();
```